How to mock Files API from java.nio.file.*
I am using Java nio API and have a below code, but unable to perform mocking on the below code.
Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
long sizeInBytes = Files.size(path);
long recordCount = 0;
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset()).skip(1)) {
    recordCount = lines.count();
}

Code I wrote below is
public class SomeTest {
    private Path path;
    @ClassRule
    public static final TemporaryFolder testdata = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Paths.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
        
        path = mock(Path.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAbRequestAuditTasklet() throws Exception {
        final Path path = testdata.newFile().toPath();
        
        Answer<Stream<String>> answer = new Answer<Stream<String>>() {
            public Stream<String> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return Stream.of("A", "B");
            }
        };
        
        when(Paths.get(testdata.getRoot().toURI())).thenReturn(path);  //line-24 - here exception is coming
        when(Files.size(any())).thenReturn(5000L);
        when(Files.lines(any(), any())).thenAnswer(answer);
    }
}

stacktrace
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:98)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at 


What exception do you get? Maybe add the relevant part of the stacktrace?

Yes added the stack trace

Is testData, testData.getRoot(), or path null? Either way, you don't mock every individual line in a method, you just mock the method.

Could you please show some working example? Even if I used when(Paths.get(any())) - giving me the same exception

In general an in-memory filesystem tends to be used for tests, like https://github.com/google/jimfs. This does not answer the question, of course, sorry about that :)
